# Cant read React state data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm developing a react application and in my state I have the data saved that I try to read. When I **JSON.stringify** the **device** data "console.log"'it out, look like this:

---

```
{
  "ActTime": 1509988664,
  "ServerTime": "2017-11-06 18:17:44",
  "Sunrise": "07:25",
  "Sunset": "15:53",
  "result": [
    {
      "AddjMulti": 1,
      "AddjMulti2": 1,
      "AddjValue": 0,
      "AddjValue2": 0,
      "BatteryLevel": 255,
      "CustomImage": 0,
      "Data": "On",
      "Description": "",
      "Favorite": 1,
      "HardwareID": 2,
      "HardwareName": "Controller",
      "HardwareType": "OpenZWave USB",
      "HardwareTypeVal": 21,
      "HaveDimmer": true,
      "HaveGroupCmd": true,
      "HaveTimeout": false,
      "ID": "00000501",
      "Image": "Light",
      "IsSubDevice": false,
      "LastUpdate": "2017-11-06 15:42:00",
      "Level": 0,
      "LevelInt": 0,
      "MaxDimLevel": 100,
      "Name": "Vardagsrum",
      "Notifications": "false",
      "PlanID": "0",
      "PlanIDs": [
        0
      ],
      "Protected": false,
      "ShowNotifications": true,
      "SignalLevel": "-",
      "Status": "On",
      "StrParam1": "",
      "StrParam2": "",
      "SubType": "Switch",
      "SwitchType": "On/Off",
      "SwitchTypeVal": 0,
      "Timers": "false",
      "Type": "Light/Switch",
      "TypeImg": "lightbulb",
      "Unit": 1,
      "Used": 1,
      "UsedByCamera": false,
      "XOffset": "0",
      "YOffset": "0",
      "idx": "3"
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK",
  "title": "Devices"
}
```

---

If I want to read the status data I just do: **device['status']** I get "OK", but what if I want to access the **result** data in the **device**?

I thought that **device['result'][0]['Status']** would give my 'Ok, but I just get *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined* ???

How do I read the result data in the device??

Comment: What you have works for me and looks right.

Comment: `device['result'][0]['Status']` works if the data is populated as you say. You are probably trying to access the data before it exists.

Comment: nop, it exists...the json is tha actual data.

Comment: If it did exist you wouldn't get that error (https://jsfiddle.net/9hsnwfrc/). The error means that `device` doesn't have property `result`. I'm not saying that you are not having the data you claim you have. I'm saying that you might be trying to access the data before you received it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this `device['result'][0]['Status']` you want to ensure your device data is not a string but a proper JSON object. You could `JSON.parse()` to convert it if it's not already an object.
Also ensure the data is available before trying that.

Comment: If it wasn't an object already, they wouldn't be getting `OK` when accessing `device['status']`.

Comment: Data is available. Just got "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" from JSON.parse()

Comment: What that means is that, the data is already a JS object, no need to parse it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use map method over result array.

Something like this:

```
result.map((item,index)=>{

   console.log(item[index].AddjMulti);

})
```

Comment: check the nullity of your object bro. Don't devote the answer. I use this thing almost everyday. Trust me.

Comment: This is what i dont understand, i can console.log ths result data and acually see the data int ths console output in chrome. But i can access it!! I'm getting really fed up with this...

Comment: use this  
 
static defaultProps={
  nameOfYourObject:{}
}

Comment: You're right, i'll missed the 'undefined' logging in the console printout...thanks. Added the access later and then it worked

Comment: Awesome. Could you just edit the answer appending this thing and upvote now? :p